# How to integrate Vaadin 14 (application written in java only) with a new React module?

Tags: java, reactjs, vaadin

We have a Vaadin app written in Java only. Our architecture principles changed and we plan to write a new module of this app using React. This module will have its separate route.

We want to write frontend in React and then communicate via REST API with backend. Is this achievable in an app like we have now (a vaadin monolith)?

Can we fully separate backend from frontend just for this new module?

How can we handle app build with the new React module? Is this still going to be a monolith?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right forum for question like this, go Vaadin Discord chat instead -> https://discord.com/channels/732335336448852018/1009205986646560909